# Proof that $42\mid x_n$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I was given to prove that for $x_n = 7^n + (-6)^n -1$, then $42\mid x_n$ $\forall n\geq 1$. I know that working in $\bmod 42$ is the obvious choice here, but I initially thought that since $42= 2\cdot 3 \cdot 7$, then if I could prove $2\mid x_n$, $3\mid x_n$, and $7\mid x_n$, then that would imply that $42\mid x_n$. So here is essentially what I came up with:

Prove $2\mid x_n$, $3\mid x_n$, and $7\mid x_n$:

Show $2\mid x_n$:

Working in mod$2$, we would have that $7^n + (-6)^n -1 \equiv 0$ mod$2$. But $7 \equiv 1 \bmod 2$, and similarly $(-6) \equiv 0$ mod$2$. Which implies that $7^n \equiv 1\bmod 2$, and $(-6)^n \equiv 0\bmod 2$, for all $n$. Thus, we get $1 + 0 -1 =0$, which is true, which implies $2\mid x_n$.

The argument is precisely the same for the remaining two statements, just working in $\bmod 3$ and $\bmod 7$. So would this way be equivalent to simply working in $\bmod 42$ and therefore showing $42\mid x_n$? I know this way is unnecessarily long and pretty much pointless in terms of efficiency, I just want to know if it still works.

Comment: Try to use induction

Comment: Yes I know I can use induction on this, but I wanted to prove it using modular arithmetic, I just wanna know if my argument works.

Comment: $7^{2k+1}+(-6)^{2k+1}-1=7^{2k}+6^{2k}-1+7\cdot 6 \cdot (7^{2k-1}-6^{2k-1})$

Comment: If you prove that $2|x_n$, $3|x_n$, $7|x_n$, it's enough to state that $42|x_n$, because it means that $x_n$ prime factorization contain all these primes.

Comment: $7^{n}-1-(-6)^n=(7-1)(7^{n-1}+...+1)-(-1)^n 6^n$ is divisible by 6, so you can make both 2 and 3 with one shot.

Comment: You may be interested in the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: It's a little easier to just work mod 7 and mod 6.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is right, and not more complicated than calculating mod 42, which implies proving it for 2 ,3, 7-